# Django Rest Framework: Writable Nested Serializers get or create

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to create a writable nested serializer in such a way that the foreign key object gets created if it's non-existent, kind of like this:

```
class A(models.Model):
    x = models.CharField()

class B(models.Model):
    a = models.ForeignKey(A)
    y = models.CharField()

class ASerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = A

class BSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    a = ASerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = B

    def create(self, validated_data):
        a_data = validated_data.pop('a', None)

        try:
            a = A.objects.get(x=a_data.get('x', None))
        except A.DoesNotExist:
            a = A.objects.create(**a_data)

        b = B.objects.create(a=a, **validated_data)
        return b
```

I want to be able to accept POST requests that either checks if an instance of A already exists. 
If not, it automatically creates it and associates it with B. Is this the correct way? I just get an error 500 on my POSTs.
I've been stuck for a day now on how to approach this. Help needed and very much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Could you add error message, please?